# Более компактный код

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('.news-block_main').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_main').hide('fast');
  }
);
$('.news-block_2').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_2').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_2').hide('fast');
  }
);
$('.news-block_3').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_3').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_3').hide('fast');
  }
);
$('.news-block_4').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_4').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_4').hide('fast');
  }
);
$('.news-block_5').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_5').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_5').hide('fast');
  }
);
$('.news-block_6').hover(
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_6').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.news-block-hover_6').hide('fast');
  }
);
```

```css
.news-blocks {
  max-width: 1210px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.news-list {
  position: relative;
  height: 676px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.anews {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 33.33%;
}
.news-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #555;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-block:hover h2 {
  color: #000;
}
.news-block h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: ProximaBold;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.news-block-stf {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 90px 100px;
}
.news-block.news-block_main {
  width: 200%;
  height: 202%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.news-block.news-block_2 {
  top: 0;
  left: 200%;
  border-left: 4px solid #0e0f16;
}
.news-block.news-block_3 {
  top: 100%;
  left: 200%;
  border-left: 4px solid #0e0f16;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
}
.news-block.news-block_4 {
  top: 202%;
  left: 0%;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
}
.news-block.news-block_5 {
  top: 202%;
  left: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
  border-left: 4px solid #0e0f16;
}
.news-block-hover_5 img {
  width: 398px;
  height: 225px;
}
.news-block.news-block_6 {
  top: 202%;
  left: 200%;
  border-top: 4px solid #0e0f16;
  border-left: 4px solid #0e0f16;
}
.news-block .news-block-descr {
  padding: 21px 20px 11px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.news-block-descr {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%;
  left: 0;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 15px 10px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  z-index: 5;
}
.news-block_2 .news-block-descr,
.news-block_3 .news-block-descr,
.news-block_4 .news-block-descr,
.news-block_5 .news-block-descr,
.news-block_6 .news-block-descr {
  bottom: 11%;
}
.news-block:hover .news-block-stats {
  color: #000;
}
.news-block-stats span.news-comm {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.news-block-stats span {
  font-family: ProximaLight;
}
.news-block .news-block-step_to_full_main,
.news-block-step_to_full_2,
.news-block-step_to_full_3,
.news-block-step_to_full_4,
.news-block-step_to_full_5,
.news-block-step_to_full_6 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  z-index: 10;
}
.news-block .news-block-step_to_full_main {
  right: -60px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  position: absolute;
}
.news-block:hover .news-block-step_to_full_main,
.news-block-step_to_full_2,
.news-block-step_to_full_3,
.news-block-step_to_full_4,
.news-block-step_to_full_5,
.news-block-step_to_full_6 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  z-index: 10;
}
.news-banner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-banner img {
  width: 1210px;
}
.news-block-hover_main,
.news-block-hover_2,
.news-block-hover_3,
.news-block-hover_4,
.news-block-hover_5,
.news-block-hover_6 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-list">
  <div id="actuallynews" class="anews">
    <div class="news-block news-block_main " style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/NG5QZQv.jpg);">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="news-block-hover_main" style="display:none;">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XjdCeR1.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block news-block_2" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
      <div class="news-block-hover_2" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block news-block_3" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
      <div class="news-block-hover_3" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block news-block_4" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
      <div class="news-block-hover_4" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block news-block_5" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
      <div class="news-block-hover_5" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block news-block_6" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
      <div class="news-block-hover_6" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сейчас как мне кажется - он выглядит очень костыльно и неправильно, но при этом работает как мне надо. Что можно сделать с JS - чтобы это выглядело более менее нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Как заметил @Maqsood в данном случае можно обойтись вообще без использования js. Если возможно лучше использовать `:hover` css селектор, вместо навешивания множества js событий.

Создайте объект с селекторами, для элементов которые будете скрывать или показывать. Затем пройдитесь по нему, добавляя события.

```
var blocks = {
 '.news-block_main': '.news-block-hover_main',
 '.news-block_2': '.news-block-hover_2',
 //... other blocks
};

//es6
for( var selector in blocks ){ 
   //let variable will "remember" it's value when event fire.
   //it doesn't hoist (accessible only in for loop). 

   let $hover_block = $( blocks[ selector ] );
   $( selector ).hover(
       function() { $hover_block.show('fast'); },
       function() { $hover_block.hide('fast'); }
   );
}

//es5 version
for( var selector in blocks ){
   var $hover_block = $( blocks[ selector ] );
   //"var"  variable will change it value on each iteration
   // it hoist to top of function (if any). 

   //need to create separate scope for each iteration.
   ( function( $hover_block ){
       $( selector ).hover(
           function() { $hover_block.show('fast'); },
           function() { $hover_block.hide('fast'); }
       );
   }( $hover_block ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я могу посоветовать использовать только CSS.

Пример моей реализации:

```
.my_div {
    width: 402px;
    height: 224px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.my_div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 402px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.my_div:hover > span{
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="my_div" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEyKu1J.jpg);">
    <span><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Onvos6.png"></span>
</div>
```

Посмотрите как работает: [jsfiddle.net/eLxggt4g/](https://jsfiddle.net/eLxggt4g/)